# A book I read based in England

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a book or series of books around 1992, and these are the things I can remember

- if it's a single book it is very long, otherwise could be a series;
- I'm pretty sure the protagonist was a young boy;
- the protagonist had to collect a number of objects which were circles with a cross through the middle;
- the objects were all similar in appearance but were made of wood, iron, etc. ;
- one of the objects was somehow related to water and found on a viking ship;
- there was a cyclic event of "dark forces" that the protagonist needed to combat; and
- the year the book began there was a particularly harsh winter and this was associated with the activities of the "dark forces".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This sounds like [*The Dark is Rising*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Is_Rising_Sequence#The_Dark_Is_Rising), the second book in the [The Dark is Rising sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Is_Rising_Sequence).

Answer (score 20):

This sounds like [*The Dark is Rising* series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Is_Rising_Sequence) by Susan Cooper.
It's about an 11 year old boy who must wield the power of Light to fight the Dark.
He has six objects with a circle and cross made of wood, iron, bronze etc.
A movie was adapted from the series, called [*The Seeker: The Dark is Rising*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Seeker%3a_The_Dark_Is_Rising).

Comment: Sorry I can't mark both as answer ... but you both got it exactly right. I upvoted you anyway...