# I am looking for a series of novels from when I was a teen young adult

Tags: story-identification

The book is about a couple of modern day teens and their "uncle Merryweather". Content was religious.  Would have been published prior to 1985.  Seems like magic and druidism was prevelant in the novels.

Comment: Are you sure it was “Merryweather”? Not their uncle “Merriman Lyon,” by any chance?

Comment: Actually Great-uncle Merry (Dark is Rising series by Susan Cooper). Kids are named Barney, Jane, and Simon Drew, Will Stanton, and depending if you got to books 4 or 5, Bran Davies.

Comment: @mkennedy: Are you planning to write up an answer?

Comment: And Uncle Merry was Merlin https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Is_Rising_Sequence

Comment: Anything else you can remember? From [this list](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info), for instance?

Comment: Do you recall them collecting anything? e,g, In the Dark is Rising Will is given a metal circle with a cross in it (like ⛒) which he threads through his belt.

Comment: I came in planning to ask exactly the question that Adamant asked. But since he beat me to it, I won't bother. :-)

Comment: @fuzzyboots go ahead

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22023/childrens-fantasy-series-with-a-symbol-consisting-of-a-circle-divided-into-quar

Answer (score 5):

You may be looking for the *[The Dark is Rising Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Is_Rising_Sequence)* series by Susan Cooper.

> **Simon, Jane, and Barney Drew**: The main characters of the first novel, the Drew siblings, are human children who have known **Merriman Lyon** as their "*Great Uncle Merry*" for years. While on holiday in Cornwall, they get caught up in the battle between the Light and the Dark and join the search for the Things of Power. In the first novel, *Over Sea, Under Stone*, they search for the legendary Grail of King Arthur. They also appear in the third book, *Greenwitch*, and the last book in the series, *Silver on the Tree*. In the poem featured prominently throughout **The Dark Is Rising**, they are the ones referred to as "three from the track". Their last name is linked with Will Stanton's in British paleohistory; see Stanton Drew stone circles.
>
> **Will Stanton**: The main character of the second novel, and a major character in the entire series, he is the seventh son of a seventh son, in a large, close human family. His eleventh birthday marks the beginning of his magical awakening and rise to power as the last of the Old Ones. *The Dark Is Rising* tells how he came to power, met Merriman Lyon, and accumulated the six "signs" to help fight the Dark. Will is the last of the Old Ones; no others will be born after him. In *Greenwitch*, he is invited to come to Cornwall by Merriman in order to help recover the Grail and cypher that reveals how to read the runes on the Grail. He later gives Jane a bracelet of gold engraved with the words, "power from the Greenwitch", which she throws into the sea as an offering to the Greenwitch in appreciation for its help. In *The Grey King*, Will goes to Wales to recover from sickness, where he meets Bran and awakens the Sleepers. In Silver on the Tree, Will travels with Bran to the Lost Land to recover the crystal sword Eirias, and helps to vanquish the Dark. Will is the only Old One to remain on Earth afterward, and the only one of the Light's allies who remembers the struggle against the Dark; in this, he is referred to as "the watchman", staying behind to keep watch for any attempt by the Dark to return.
>
> Cooper named Will for William Shakespeare.
>
> **Merriman Lyon**: Merriman is the first Old One. He and Will Stanton have a special bond as each of them is one end of the long line of Old Ones. It is said that with the birth and coming to power of Will Stanton, the circle of Old Ones is complete. A friend of the Drew family for over a generation, he assisted Barney, Jane, and Simon in their quest for the Grail, in addition to protecting them until their task was completed; they occasionally refer to him as "Great Uncle Merry" or "Gumerry". Throughout the series Merriman is portrayed in numerous historical periods, but particularly as King Arthur's chief adviser, the mythical Merlin, as Arthur calls him "Mer Lion", old English for "my lion", in Silver on the Tree.

They were published between 1965 to 1977, with the omnibus version being released in 1984. The book series is not particularly religious from a Christianity perspective, although the movie was marketed that way by a producer known for the *Narnia* films. It does have a fair amount of pagan and Celtic mythology in it.

[image: Over Sea Under Stone - Book cover]

Comment: If this is the one, don't forget to upvote and click on the checkmark beside the voting button to accept it. It will also be closed as a duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36374/a-book-i-read-based-in-england/36377, but that's no censure to you. We just like to keep the site tidy and group answers together.